# In ASP.NET MVC RC3 with Razor - @String.Format("{0:hh:mm:ss}", timespan) errors - bug?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

The following errors with a FormatException:

```
<td class="numeric">@String.Format("{0:hh:mm:ss}", testrun.ExecutionTime)</td>
```

Where `ExecutionTime` is a TimeSpan. This format string is valid. Is this a bug or am I missing something obvious (given the late hour - the latter is probably it).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try escaping the `:`

```
String.Format("{0:hh\\:mm\\:ss}", testrun.ExecutionTime)
```

Comment: Don't you just escape the backslash there?

Comment: @jgauffin, no you escape the `:` which are considered a special character in `string.Format`. Alternatively if you want a single backslash you could: `String.Format(@"{0:hh\:mm\:ss}", testrun.ExecutionTime)`. It's standard C#, nothing to do with MVC or razor.

Comment: I thought that `\n` would produce a line feed, but `\\n` would produce a string with backslash and 'n'.

Comment: @jgauffin it does, but he wants to insert a backslash into the string so the format parser knows he has to escape the : (: is a special character in .NET format strings). A single \ is a compiler escape char, so he has to escape the escape character so it gets past the compiler and into the format string parser.

Answer (score 3):

Aren't you looking for the `@testRun.ExecutionTime.ToString("format here")` method?

Format strings for timespan: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992632.aspx

Comment: Ah that is new in .NET 4.0.  Seemed like a glaring ommission.  Thanks.

Comment: Heh, even that approach requires "hh\\:mm\\:ss".